# How to create a Cakephp 3 Shell that overwrites files without asking permission

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Cakephp 3.2, which is awesome!

I have a shell script is very politely asking if I want to overwrite my files -I'm worried the shell won't complete its intended outcome when run as a cron job.

```
#example of current shell output
File 'webroot/example.json' exists
Do you want to overwrite? (y/n/a/q)
```

The docs say: "*If the shell’s interactive property is false, no question will be asked and the file will simply be overwritten.*" (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-files) **This seems to suggest that any shell can alter the "interactive" property but I haven't found a way to do that.**

I could probably change this to false (http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Console.Shell.html#84), but I think that would affect all shells, no thank you.

---

Example Code:

```
class ExampleShell extends Shell {

  public function initialize() {
      parent::initialize();
  }

  public function main() {
      $array = [1,2,3];
      $this->createFile('webroot/example.json', json_encode($array));  //this file already exists
  }
}
?>
```

---

#### tl;dr

Please let me know how I can make a single shell script's interactive property set to false so that it won't require a user to allow files to be overwritten. Please provide a code sample if possible, solution must not be applied globally.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest that you simply give the `interactive` property a try, just assuming that something may happen isn't a good basis for any choices.

Comment: Why use a function specifically designed to ask the user - if you specifically don't want to?

Comment: @AD7six thanks for the reply, I guess you're telling me that I'm using the cake shell method of creating the file when I could just use the php method of creating the file instead bypassing the prompt to the user. I'll try that instead, I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AD7six for the comment that helped me see the bigger picture. I was able to replace a line of code and now my cron jobs work!

```
//replaced this
$this->createFile('webroot/example.json', json_encode($array));

//with this
file_put_contents('webroot/example.json', json_encode($array));
```